# Why DND automatically turns itself on and off in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, mac, do-not-disturb, notifications

I am noticing for quite a few days that after upgrading to high sierra though DND doesn't has any custom timeline for auto on and off in system preferences it automatically turns itself on every-day at 12:00 am and turns itself off at 12:00 pm, I don't know why is this happening

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DND acts buggy in High Sierra when you set the time to midnight. I'm not sure if this applies to you but DND does not like 12:00 AM. Use any time except 12:00 AM such as 12:01 AM or 11:59 PM if you are setting DND time values.

If you set DND to turn on at 12:00 AM and off at any other time, it will show as disabled the next time you look at it and the start/end times will have been changed to 10:00 PM/7:00 AM.

I spoke with Apple and they confirmed this behavior in High Sierra.

Comment: This seems to have worked on High Sierra - I also set the on/off times to other values to make it easier to detect any regression in future.